# App para android en python

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy

Estoy haciendo mi "Hola mundo" en python, les comento que estoy ocupando Kivy para hacer esto pero al momento de ejecutar el programa me sale un error.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Contenedor_01(BoxLayout):
    None

class MainApp(App):
    title = "Hola mundo"
    def build(self):
        return Contenedor_01()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run(App)
```

Este es el error que me aparece:

> [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in
>   C:\Users\mxe01508121A.kivy\logs\kivy_17-07-17_5.txt [INFO   ] [Kivy
>   ] v1.10.0 [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21
>   2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] [INFO   ] [Factory     ]
>   194 symbols loaded [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex,
>   img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored) 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>   "C:/Users/mxe01508121A/PycharmProjects/untitled1/main.py", line 16, in
>   
>        MainApp().run(App)  TypeError: run() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Espero me puedan ayudar un saludo cordial a todos.

**Edición:**

Trás corregir el problema anterior, según lo indicado en la respuesta de FJSevilla, ahora obtengo el siguiente error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\mxe01508121A\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-07-17_44.txt        
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0        
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.4.0 - Build 20.19.15.4483'>        
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>           
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 520'>      
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 4
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.40 - Build 20.19.15.4483'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <b"WARNING: 0:7: '' :  #version directive missing">
[INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <b"WARNING: 0:7: '' :  #version directive missing">
[WARNING] [Image       ] Unable to load image <C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\glsl\default.png>
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
  File "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 140, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 899, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 291, in create_window
    super(WindowSDL, self).create_window()
  File "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1051, in create_window
    self.render_context = RenderContext()
  File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 758, in kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__ (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:12580)
  File "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 538, in __init__
    self.filename = arg
  File "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 734, in _set_filename
    mipmap=self._mipmap, nocache=self._nocache)
  File "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 435, in load
    im = loader(filename, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 201, in __init__
    self._data = self.load(filename)
  File "C:\Users\mxe01508121A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py", line 41, in load
    raise Exception('SDL2: Unable to load image')

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: Memo has agregado el código del error nuevo (supongo) como una edición de mi respuesta, esto debe ser una edición de la pregunta. La he editado y lo he añadido. Una pregunta, ¿te has instalado las dependencias de Kivy antes de instalar Kivy en si sin obtener errores? `python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew`

Answer (score 3):

`run` es un método de instancia de la clase `kivy.app.App` y como tal recibe de forma automática como primer argumento la instancia de la clase (argumento `self` por convención).

En tu caso llamas al método `run` del objeto `MainApp` (que es una instancia de la clase `App`) pero le estas pasando un segundo argumento (además del primero que se pasa de forma automática y que es la propia instancia `MainApp`) que es la clase en sí (`App`):

```
MainApp().run(App)
```

Aunque no lo veas, el método está siendo llamando como:

```
MainApp().run(MainApp, App)
```

Al método `run` no se le pasa ningún argumennto de forma explícita, su definición es:

```
def run(self):
```

Tu código debe ser:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Contenedor_01(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    title = "Hola mundo"
    def build(self):
        return Contenedor_01()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Para decirle al intérprete que no haga nada cuando se encuentre una sentencia que requiere sintáxticamente otra después (como en el caso de la definición de la clase `Contador _01`) se usa la sentencia [`pass`](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/2/controlflow.html#la-sentencia-pass).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edición:**

El nuevo error que comentas tiene pinta de ser un problema de instalación de librerias, en concreto con la dependencia `sdl2`. No se si has seguido sin errores las instruccines de instalación para Windows tal y como vienen en la documentación oficial:

https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html

Recuerda que tienes que instalar las dependencias correctamente (sin que se te muestre alguna excepción en el proceso) para que Kivy funcione sin problemas:

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
```

Comment: ya lo corri como tu me indicas pero me sale lo que pongo arriba

Comment: @Memo el código es correcto, lo acabo de ejecutar por si se me escapara algo pero no genera ningún error y la app abre sin problemas. Asegurate de haber guardado el script con el código que te doy antes de ejecutarlo de nuevo.

Comment: @Memo te dejo el código ejecutado en vivo para que veas como funciona sin problemas. si te sigue dando problemas algo está mal en tu IDE o en las bibliotecas. Saludos.